# Laravel override Login controller, login(). How do i retrieve logged in user data if i overwrite the login controller. I tried to get auth() data

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes, overriding, session-variables

I used laravel like 4 years ago. Had to work on a project on laravel and tried using my own authentication methods but mybad forgot there was already inbuilt better security authentication. I understand if my question seem to be basic.
As you can see the commented line "$userID = Auth::user()->userID;" the auth() is null therefore, userID cannot get its id from null. I am unable to get user session data in any other controllers as well.
Any kind of help or suggestions is appreciated.

P.S. i have used the default login and registration inbuilt function only required function like login is override code. I am using laravel v 4.2.3. I tried passing the userid as url parameter but then discarded it as inbuilt session data makes it more secure and easier

the login function of my controller looks like this

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function login(Request $request){
        $user = new User(); //my model User
        $result=$user->login($request); //result has the id of the user
        if ($result) {
            //$userID = Auth::user()->userID;
            return redirect()->route('homepage');
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('login');   
        }
    }
}
```

model for user login()

```
    //Auth user then let them login
    public function login($request){
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $password = $request->input('password');
        $result=DB::table('users')
                    ->where('email', $email)
                    ->where('password', $password)
                    ->get();
        return $result;
    }
```

My Routes.. its default route of "Auth::routes();"

```
Route::get('/homepage/{userID?}', function($userID = null){
    return view('index', ['userID' => $userID]);
})->name('homepage');

Route::get('/evaluate/{userID?}', function ($userID =  null) {
    return view('evaluate', ['userID' => $userID]);
})->name('evaluate');
```

Comment: which name you provide for your  users id

Comment: its just id. was userID

Answer (score 0):

I installed a fresh new laravel and tried my code again and somehow it worked. Must have made some errors when trying to override the codes. Thank you